# sandbox paypal recurring billing post data issue..not receiving post data in auto return is on

Tags: post, paypal, recurring

I am also facing many issues with new sandbox account, but by using ctrl+shift+N i can login to sandbox now..
My question is :
i am using recurring payment..i have set auto return on with PDT on..but i am not getting details on return url...when i post the details to sandbox paypal..below is the my form details...please help me to resolve this issue..

```
            <input type="hidden' name="business" value="merch_1362652447_biz@yahoo.co.in">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alices Monthly Digest">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="DIG Weekly">

            <input type="hidden" name="a1" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="p1" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="t1" value="M">

            <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="10">              
            <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
            <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">              

            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://sitename/test.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://sitename/test.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://sitename/test.php">
        </form>"
```

with form action="https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"

If i am not set auto return in that case..when user clicks return button then its gives me all required payment details ...but in case of auto return its not working...pls
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not get any details back with the current button you are using, because you are setting up a free 1 month trail.  PDT (Payment Data Transfer), only returns the information back to your site when there is a payment.  In this case, since there is a free 1 month trial, no data is returned.  If you were to change it from 0.00 to 1.00 for example, data would be returned.  If you are going to want to capture the information once a buyer completes a checkout, I would suggest using IPN.  IPN is also going to be more reliable than PDT as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i can not charge user for trail period, so is there any solution to retrive post data after successful recurring payment with free trail period.Also, I've tried with IPN (Auto return - ON, PDF - OFF, IPN - ON) but not receiving post data in notifiy_url.Please let me know correct way of checking IPN data.

Comment: IPN would be the way to go.  You would need to enable IPN in your PayPal account, and set the path to your script either within your PayPal account, or through the code using the notify_url variable.  You will want your IPN URL to be a different page, other then the return URL.  The IPN URL should be a behind the scenes page that updates your system, not the page the buyer is returned to.  Once you have ran a payment through, check the IPN history in your account to assure that it is being sent out, and there your server is responding back with a 200ok response.

Comment: In sandbox, I have enabled IPN with notify url changes and checked with IPN History page but its showing status "Retrying" for all request and after 6-10 attempts status changed to 'Failed' and showing blank http response code.Can you please tell where i am making mistake.

Comment: A retrying status means that your server is not successfully acknowledging the communication with a 200ok response.  Check the IPN message to see if there is a status code being returned.  This page may also help you as well https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/ipn/pdt/ipn-troubleshooting-tips-0

Comment: IPN issue is resolved. I was testing ipn method at localhost may be because of that its not giving me 200 response..Now i am testing it at live server then its working..But its not returning cc last 4 digit, recurring billing details like billing period, total billing frequency..so how could i get cc last 4 digit only..

Comment: Yeah, IPN will not work with localhost, as it is generated from PayPal's server, so it would try to return the IPN POST to the local host of the server.  Also IPN doesn't return the last 4 of the credit card number.

Comment: I am using API to set recurring payment. In case of API, first time i am getting details of user about payment.But how could i get the details of user at every payment cycle. I am using API to set recurring so here IPN will not play role right?. Please guide.

Comment: The IPN system would send an IPN POST to your system for every payment for the different cycles.  You would get an IPN for the profile being set up, and for each payment.  You can find more on IPN at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro

Comment: Thanks. I want to charge user for buying item on site using DODirect so that user can user there credit card..but amount paid by user should receive to end user..it means items are related to dift users and buyer money should go to that particular user's paypal email id..So how could i use API to achive this..Looking for solution...Thanks in advance..

Comment: You could use the DoDirectPayment to process the payment.  The funds would go into your account, then you could use MassPayment to send the funds to the other receivers.  You could also use Express Checkout with Parallel payments.